# How to I make this If statement work on my Django project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

The if statement looks correct to me but when i save and execute the server, the printed out information is incorrect. Its almost like the information is not being picked up. Am i missing something in my model or view? Or is there anything else that i have to add to the if statement to allow it to see the data i'm trying to have it post? Can someone point out what i'm missing here??

```
HTML code:
{% if leads.lead_status == "Active Deal" %}
    {% for lead in leads %}
        <tr>
            <td data-href="{% url 'leads:lead-detail' lead.pk %}"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i> {{ lead.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ lead.first_name|title }} {{ lead.last_name|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ lead.city|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ lead.state|upper }}</td>
            <td data-href="tel:{{ lead.phone }}">{{ lead.phone }} <i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i> </td>
            <td>$34,567.89</td>
            <td> 
                {% if lead.contract_out == "" %}
                --/--/----
                {% else %}
                {{ lead.contract_out }} 
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if lead.contract_back == "" %}
                --/--/----
                {% else %}
                {{ lead.contract_back }}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if lead.hearing_date == "" %}
                --/--/----
                {% else %}
                {{ lead.hearing_date }}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

```
views.py

class DashboardPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
    context_object_name = "leads"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        
        queryset = Lead.objects.filter(agent__user=user)
        return queryset
```

```
models.py

class Lead(models.Model):
    PROBLEM_LEAD = 'Problem Lead'
    PAY_TOO_FAR = 'Payments Too Far'
    PAY_TOO_SMALL = 'Payments Too Small'
    NPI = 'No Payment Information'
    ACTIVE = 'Active Deal'
    NO_DEAL = 'No Deal'

    choices_lead_status = [
    (PROBLEM_LEAD, 'Problem Lead'),
    (PAY_TOO_FAR,'Payments Too Far'),
    (PAY_TOO_SMALL,'Payments Too Small'),
    (NPI,'No Payment Information'),
    (ACTIVE,'Active Deal'),
    (NO_DEAL,'No Deal')
    ]

    choices_lead_owner = [
        ("Settlement, New",'Settlement, New'),
        ("Lead, Sales",'Lead, Sales'),
        # ("REPS",'Doe, John')
    ]

    # pill one: Client details
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    secondary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50000, blank=True)
    lead_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choices_lead_status, blank=True)
    lead_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choices_lead_owner, blank=True)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
    contract_out = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    contract_back = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    hearing_date = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

Comment: You can’t check if an element inside a queryset is true or false or have a certain value. 
You should check it inside the forloop. I’ll write the code in the answer in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check if an element inside a queryset has a certain value or whatsoever. You should loop through the elements of the query set and then check, for each element, if has that status.

HTML code:

```
#Remove the {% if leads.lead_status == "Active Deal" %}  line!
    {% for lead in leads %}
        {% if lead.lead_status == "Active Deal" %} #this checks if the lead has that lead_status
        <tr>
            <td data-href="{% url 'leads:lead-detail' lead.pk %}"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i> {{ lead.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ lead.first_name|title }} {{ lead.last_name|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ lead.city|title }}</td>
            <td>{{ lead.state|upper }}</td>
            <td data-href="tel:{{ lead.phone }}">{{ lead.phone }} <i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i> </td>
            <td>$34,567.89</td>
            <td> 
                {% if lead.contract_out == "" %}
                --/--/----
                {% else %}
                {{ lead.contract_out }} 
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if lead.contract_back == "" %}
                --/--/----
                {% else %}
                {{ lead.contract_back }}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if lead.hearing_date == "" %}
                --/--/----
                {% else %}
                {{ lead.hearing_date }}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %} #add this endif
    {% endfor %}
#remove this{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped a lot. If you don't mind, do you have a discord where i could reach out in the event i have more questions? If not no worries I understand. Thanks a ton anyways